# Employee can see there own info only odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

Is it possible that the employee can edit their own information only in employee module and can see other employee info but cannot edit other employees info?

I tried with record rule but this is not what I want :(

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

You can do that if user is associated with employee there is a field in employee user_id add record rule in employee that user_id = user.id and gave your permissions accordingly.

Comment: Using this record rule user can see their own records but can not see other user records instead I want user can edit his/her records but can see other user records only.

Comment: write your record rule accordingly so that they can see others and update their own